# Totaling variables in a while loop for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, counter, cumulative-sum

My program is meant to be a virtual McDonald's.  Everything works fine, but I need help with one of the totaling methods.  At the bottom of this program I totaled the total number of fees etc.  Now I need to total how many customers go through the program.  This is hard because there is no set number to the customers. This program is run on a while loop and the total amount of customers is completely up to the user.  How do I total the total amount of customers?

```
num1 = 4.87
num2 = 5.03
num3 = 5.50
num4 = 9.45
num5 = 1.29
num6 = 2.19
num7 = 2.29
tax = 0.0565
customer = 0
nextcustomer = "yes"
dailytax = 0
dailysubtotal = 0
dailyfinalbill = 0
dailynum_customers = 0

while nextcustomer != "no":
    amtgiven = 0
    change = 0
    quantity = 0
    foodprice = 0
    totalprice = 0
    billtax = 0
    finalbill = 0
    itemnum = 0
    print "Welcome to Virtual McDonald's!"
    print "Item:                     Meal/item:                          Price:"
    print "1                          Big Mac Meal                        4.87"
    print "2                          Quarter Pounder Meal                5.03"
    print "3                          Chicken Nuggets Meal (5 piece)      5.50"
    print "4                          ChickenNuggets Meal (10 piece)      9.45"
    print "5                          Apple Pie                           1.29"
    print "6                          Large Drink                         2.19"
    print "7                          Large Fries                         2.29"

    customer = raw_input ("Would you like to order? (If not type no)")
    while customer != "no":

        while itemnum != -1: 
            itemnum = input("Enter the item you would like to purchase! ")
            if itemnum == -1:
                break
            quantity = input("How many of this item do you want? ")

            if itemnum == 1:
                foodprice = quantity * num1
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 2:
                foodprice = quantity * num2
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 3:
                foodprice = quantity * num3
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 4:
                foodprice = quantity * num4
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 5:
                foodprice = quantity * num5
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 6:
                foodprice = quantity * num6
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 7:
                foodprice = quantity * num7
                totalprice += foodprice

        billtax = totalprice * tax
        finalbill = totalprice + billtax        
        dailytax = dailytax + billtax
        dailysubtotal = dailysubtotal + totalprice
        dailyfinalbill = dailyfinalbill + finalbill

        print "Your total bill without tax is... ", round(totalprice,2)
        print "Your total tax is... ", round(billtax,2)
        print "Your final bill is... ", round(finalbill,2)
        amtgiven = input("How much do you want to pay with? ")
        change = amtgiven - finalbill
        print "Your change is... ", round(change,2)
        break
    nextcustomer = raw_input("Is there another customer? (yes or no) ") 

print "The total amount of sales without added tax recieved today is...",round(dailysubtotal,2)
print "The total amount of taxes received today is...",round(dailytax,2)
print "The total amount of sales with added tax recieved today is...",round(dailyfinalbill,2)
print dailynum_customers
```

Comment: what does a total customer means , unique or duplicate customer can be counted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `numCustomers = 0` to the top.

Also, change this:

```
while nextcustomer != "no":
    amtgiven = 0
```

to this:

```
while nextcustomer != "no":
    numCustomers += 1
    amtgiven = 0
```

In the end, add this:

```
print 'total customers:', numCustomers
```

Comment: It looks like `dailynum_customers` was intended for this purpose, IMO.  But otherwise, I think that's it.

Comment: @InspectorG4dget amtgiven is used for a different calculation, so I can't use it.